# extracting the attribute value and cut the string using perl

Tags: shell, perl

`<Student>
<test subject="/school/class/twelve/maths.txt"/>
<test subject="/school/class/eleven/physics.txt"/>
</Student>`

I want to take the values of "subject" attibute, and then cut the string starting from class.
for example, the output must be two strings as: twelve/maths.txt and eleven/physics.txt
Could anyone please help to do this using shell script or perl?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code writing service, and we also do not teach programming from scratch. If you need help with your school assignment that is fine, but you need to show some effort first. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and then do some research. It's likely your course offers resources that help you get started. Once you have, and you are getting stuck with code to show, feel free to ask and we will help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

Easy in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around Perl's [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for /Student/test echo substring-after(@subject, '/school/class/') ;
```

Comment: I keep forgetting you have that thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in steps. First to get the attribute value, then taking the substring

```
INPUT=$(sed -n 's/.*subject="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' *.xml)
echo "the value of subject attribute=" $INPUT
```

But this result in the output:

the value of subject attribute=/school/class/twelve/maths.txt /school/class/eleven/physics.txt

after this I have taken the substring:

```
SubString1=$(echo $INPUT| cut -d'/' -f 5)
echo "SubString1=" $SubString1
nospaces=${SubString1## } # remove leading spaces
SubString1=${nospaces%% } # remove trailing spaces
SubString2=$(echo $INPUT| cut -d'/' -f 11)
echo "SubString2=" $SubString2
```

and the output is 
SubString1=maths.txt
SubString2=physics.txt